Help finding LDO IC with marking on device: YSJG, YS2G SOT23-5
I am searching for a few days now for what is presumably a LDO. The package is SOT23-5, marking: YSJG, YS2G SOT-23-5

please add a clear, in-focus, closeup picture of the IC and an overall picture of the surrounding circuitry

Looking at this SMD marking database for YS components, a YS in a SOT-23-5 package is going to land you one of the following:
R1210N362D - Nisshinbo - Boost Switching Regulator IC Positive Fixed 1 Output 3mA
RT9169H-31GB - Richtek - Linear Voltage Regulator IC Positive Fixed 1 Output 100mA SOT-23-5

It it's Richtek then OP omitted part of the marking, because it will almost certainly be either YS=*** or YS-***.

Possibly a MCP1754T-5002E/OT LDO made by Microchip, but without a picture it's impossible to confirm.


(Source: lcsc.com)

I have checked with Richtek  and Nisshinbo, they feedback it is not their components.

@FanglianWANG Not sure why you commented this under my answer, but I'm not surprised.

sorry, I don't know how to open the question again, so I add a comment.
